# Show/Hide element in dropdown depending another dropdown

Tags: jquery

I have 2 dropdown :

```
<select id="MainList">
    <option value="0">----</option>
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option value="2">B</option>
    <option value="3">C</option>
    <option value="4">D</option>
</select>

<select id="ChildList">
    <option value="0">----</option>
    <option value="5">E</option>
    <option value="6">F</option>
    <option value="7">G</option>
    <option value="8">H</option>
</select>
```

I'd like when I select the value "B" in the first dropdown hide or disable some values in the ChildList. Sample if : C in first hide or disable G in second, if D in first hide or disable G and H in second.

Thanks

Comment: u can get result by using 'Ajax'..

Comment: its seems like a state region selection!!!!

Comment: Are all of the values and relationships known at the time of page load? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Need client side solution, it's clear ... I need disable/hide some values in a dropdown depending of the value of an another dropdown :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try something like this..

use this code to get text of selected option-

```
var text = $("#MainList option:selected").text();
```

then use `switch cases(like case0-hide D, case1-hide E)`, and to hide options in child list use this code-

```
 $("#ChildList option[value=valueYouNeedToHide]").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

To enable on of the option :

```
$("#ChildList option[value=valueYouNeedToShow]").removeAttr("disabled");
```

Hope this helps you at some extent..

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery:

```
$('#MainList').change(function() {
    $('#ChildList option').removeAttr("disabled");

    if ($(this).val() == 3) {
        $('#ChildList option[value=7]').attr("disabled","disabled");
    }

    // etc..
});
```

Hope this works... in Chrome null works to un-disable things, but I'm not sure about other browsers.

Edit: Changed to removeAttr, much better. Thanks ChristopheCVB.

Comment: You can also use .removeAttr('disable')